# Find the optimum circle in an infinite grid

Tags: math, geometry, fastest-algorithm

Consider an \$n \times n\$ grid of integers which is part of an infinite grid. The top left coordinate of the \$n \times n\$ grid of integers is \$(0, 0)\$.

The task is to find a circle which when overlaid on the grid gives the largest sum of values inside it.  The constraints are:

- The circle has its centre at \$(x, x)\$ for some value \$x\$ which is not necessarily an integer. Notice that both dimensions have the same value.
- The radius of the circle is \$r\$ and is not necessarily an integer.
- The circle must include the point \$(0, 0)\$ within it.
- All points outside of the \$n \times n\$ grid  contribute zero to the sum.
- The center of the circle can be outside the \$n \times n\$ grid provided the other conditions are met.

Here is a picture of a \$10 \times 10\$ grid with two circles overlaid.

[image]

The larger circle has its center at \$(-20, -20)\$.

The two parameters are therefore \$x\$ and \$r\$.  Although there are in principle an infinite number of options, in fact only a finite subset are relevant.

The matrix in this case is:

```
[[ 3 -1  1  0 -1 -1 -3 -2 -2  2]
 [ 0  0  3  0  0 -1  2  0 -2  3]
 [ 2  0  3 -2  3  1  2  2  1  1]
 [-3  0  1  0  1  2  3  1 -3 -1]
 [-3 -2  1  2  1 -3 -2  2 -2  0]
 [-1 -3 -3  1  3 -2  0  2 -1  1]
 [-2 -2 -1  2 -2  1 -1  1  3 -1]
 [ 1  2 -1  2  0 -2 -1 -1  2  3]
 [-1 -2  3 -1  0  0  3 -3  3 -2]
 [ 0 -3  0 -1 -1  0 -2 -3 -3 -1]]
```

The winning criterion is worst case time complexity as a function of \$n\$. That is using big Oh notation, e.g. \$O(n^4)\$.

Comment: Is centroid on (x,x) or (x,y), requiring two axis be same?

Comment: @l4m2 The center of the circle has to be at (x, x). That is (-4, -4), (1, 1) etc. Does that answer your question?

Comment: OK. It's just not that reasonable so I confirm. so a circle cover (x,y) iff it cover (y,x)

Comment: What determines if a square is covered? Is it 50%, the centre, fully covered or something else?

Comment: Or is it based on the coverage of grid points?

Comment: @NickKennedy It's just based on coverage of the grid points.

Comment: Why the downvote??

Comment: If you replaced the hard boundary with a Gaussian kernel weighting, you could maybe do gradient descent. the problem kind of reminds me of SVMs.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), O(n^4)

```python
def CPos(x1, y1, x2, y2):
	return (x1*x1-x2*x2+y1*y1-y2*y2)/2/(x1-x2+y1-y2)

def f(A):
	Ret = A[0][0]
	n = len(A)
	for baseY in range(n):
		for baseX in range(n):
			if baseY == 0 and baseX == 0:
				continue
			dBase = abs(baseX - baseY)
			Sum = 0
			Buf = [[[CPos(baseX, baseY, 0, 0), 1], 0, 0]]
			for y in range(n):
				for x in range(n):
					d = abs(x - y)
					if x+y <= baseX+baseY:
						Sum = Sum + A[y][x]
						if d > 0 and x+y < baseX+baseY:
							Buf += [[[CPos(baseX, baseY, x, y), 2], -A[y][x]]]
					else:
						if d < 0:
							Buf += [[[CPos(baseX, baseY, x, y), 0], A[y][x]]]
			Buf = sorted(Buf, key=lambda k: k[0]) # Radix sort
			i = 0
			if Ret < Sum:
				Ret = Sum
			while len(Buf[i]) < 3:
				Sum = Sum + Buf[i][1]
				if Buf[i][0] != Buf[i+1][0]:
					if Ret < Sum:
						Ret = Sum
				i = i + 1
	return Ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVNNj5swED3Dr3DVCwSjtc0tCpV2@weq7aWVxYEU00XJmhUQ1fz6dD6cKM22UiUDnnkzb96Mzdu6vIy@Op8714vPX8Y5C1qKFZ5g4GvybZpMbjlNXgCyCboMZhNMserNqsvVbCDkwTxkBBTkytMUyfrsEZOf3SJq8WhVAytNPBhH5wFLk36cxL6d3XcxeDG1/qfLPKZcgW/3QDL0MaOuhRKt72IcmhSQ/Bj9MviTQ6N7AhAKtvs547iS03NEv55eAVO4fTr1sLXW0gQoVHKkFApWLoVueNs0mIAK13fqyB3eu5MuigggYM3ZB62EYhW7mlsoqFyMj9rwXcDs1saGJiKQ1olPsXki@Fs@dVT8q6UAJwstGWipjOxN5HfH2W1vS@0ug/1PUgWkf3DybOdxWlyXgSHFwa31sX3dd604bMUB7kUuPornthsCxdFBX44GROAV2uEwWAjfKDDR@vUyHB3dKKC2AzDtRMVxtzNk0GruEjijQzXiQ81GodHcXg/nrupdXRI4ALO@/h@An9@mwS9Zn1lbyVJLLRV@cIFtcMHQrQJ3JRWDBj9GVuA35EdDot/AG66dLTFW08MQkkWgNOS9FKASCiH2YDQBCqFIR0FUmbJJZ2TU0txoYumsDfeGwiTLB25kpnZIIUdzYhU1Nnl@/g0)

For each point assume the circle go through it(`Base[XY]`), then radius decrease from infinity. Store when the points enter/leave circle, sort it and only consider these step.

Comment: This is very cool. I will try to understand what your method is exactly.